# Add Name to Google Map Marker

Tags: javascript, google-maps, dictionary

I'm trying to build a map using Google Map Javascript Api and display the marker but the name doesn't display.

[image]

I'm trying to make it looks like in the embed version like this:

[image]

Here's my code so far

```
function initMap() {
  var uluru = {lat: 30.070923, lng: -95.5112095};
  var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: 17,
    center: uluru
  });
  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: uluru,
    map: map
  });
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Is your hope that you can simply point at a location, and if that location has a name associated with it, the name would appear?

Comment: Yes, actually my main goal is to display the location of the hospital then hide the other hospital on the area. That force me to use Google map API to control the styling of the map. but I can't display the name marker.

Answer (score 0):

When you create a map marker simply by giving coordinates for that marker, the marker won't have a name other than one you give it yourself. The marker won't simply pickup the name of something at or near the location you select.

You're going to need to Place Search API: https://developers.google.com/places/web-service/search

...if you want to find names of place at or near your selected location.